# Webpack code splitting, relative URL

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to write a library using webpack. I'm using code splitting with `require.ensure` in my main file. Problem is that it will try to resolve all chunks from base url. Is it possible to make it relative to entry-point?

For example, I add my entry-point as

```
<script src="node_modules/mylib/index.js">
```

When this file does `require.ensure('./dep.js')` it will try to load `/dep.js` instead of `node_modules/mylib/dep.js`.

I've made a workaround by manipulating `<base>` tag, but it's really an ugly hack. I feel like there should be a more "webpacky" solution.

Comment: Can you try https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath ?

Comment: It works! Please make an answer, I'll make it accepted. I needed this option: `__webpack_public_path__`

Comment: Cool to hear. Added an answer. Hopefully it's clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in [publicPath](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) related settings. It can be set dynamically during runtime by using `__webpack_public_path__ = window.resourceBaseUrl;` kind of declaration.

Comment: So, what you are suggesting here is to set this `resourceBaseUrl` a global variable from the server side, so it can be used in your webpack bundle, right?

Comment: Correct. You can control it through server like that.