# Webpack loading split chunks relative to main output file

Tags: webpack-4, code-splitting

In my project I'm splitting Webpack into different files, the output is going to the web accessible `/js` directory.

When I import the `main.js` file and it tries to load the dynamic files I get this error

```
Error: "Loading chunk controller/About failed.
(error: [...]/controller/About.js)"
```

Which makes perfect sense, but how can I get Webpack to load that relative to the web `/js` directory; i.e. I want it to load `.../js/controller/About.js` instead of `.../controller/About.js`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack code splitting, relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675286/webpack-code-splitting-relative-url)